# ¿Que significa :: en java?

Tags: java

Buscando cómo ordenar una lista de objetos por un parametro me encontre con esta solución:

```
lista.sort(
    Comparator.comparing(EntradaLoteVo::getFechaRecepcionLote)
       .thenComparingInt(EntradaLoteVo::getId));
```

Y me llama la atención esto: `EntradaLoteVo::getFechaRecepcionLote`. ¿Es una expresión lambda? No he podido encontrar explicaciones en internet porque no se como se llama. Creo que retorna el valor que tengo en la lista que corresponde a la clase `EntradaLoteVo` y ejecuta la operación `getFechaRecepcionLote` para cada elemento y luego `sort` lo ordena. ¿Pero qué más puede hacer?

Comment: checa [esto](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`::` se llama Referencia de Metodo. Fue introducido en Java 8.

Por mucho tiempo se utilizaron las interfaces como callbacks para procesos asincronos como por ejemplo cuando se queria tener la respuesta del servidor o cuando se queria crear un nuevo hilo:

```
new Thread(new Runnable{
  @Override
  public void run()
  {
    // se ejecuta el callback
  }
}).run();
```

Ahora puedes hacer algo parecido enviando las referencias de los metodo para utilizarlos como callbacks y evitar esa sintaxis tan complejas:

```
public void LoginUsuario(String usuario, String pass, Consumer<bool,String> loginCallback)
{
   // logeamos usuarios con el servido..
   //
    boolean usuarioValido = true;
    String token = "adsfasdfadf";
    loginCallback.apply(usuarioValido, token);
}

loginUsuario("einer","123", (valido, token) -> {
   // vlidamos si es valido
});
```

`(valido, token) -> {}` es un metodo valido que traducido seria:

```
public void callback_respuesta(boolean valido, String token)
{
   // validamos respuesta
}
```

Que adaptandolo a tu pregunta seria:

```
loginUsuario("einer","123",  clasedelMetodo::callback_respuesta);
```

Esto lo que hace es enviar la referencia del metodo `callback_respuesta` al metodo `loginUsuario`.

Esto se le llama funciones lambda. Existen 3 tipos que son : [`Function`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html), [`Supplier`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html) y [`Consummer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html). Es bueno notar que al final las 3 son interfaces que es un truco que el compilador hace para aceptar ese tipo de sintaxis.

Esto es igual a las [`Func<T, T1, T2.., TResult>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151(v=vs.110).aspx) y [`Action<T, T2...>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8(v=vs.110).aspx) de C#.

Comment: Creo que el tercer tipo de función lambda a la que te refieres es [Predicate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html)