# java 8 Lambda expresion

Tags: java, lambda

Buenas , alguien puede explicar de forma detallada que hace esta expresion en concreto?

```
listModels.addAll(listaDao.stream().map(this::personEntityToPersonModel).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

tengo el metodo :

```
 private PersonModel personEntityToPersonModel(PersonEntity personEntity){
//codigo...
}
```

o sea sé que es lo que hace pero no como lo hace me gustaria comprenderlo ya que por ejemplo al referenciar el metodo no le esta pasando ningún parametro aparentemente , muchas gracias :) estoy un poco pez en java 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la pregunta [¿Que significa :: en java?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/107152/que-significa-en-java) se explica que significan los `::`.

Básicamente, en java 8 ahora los métodos se pueden enviar como parámetros. El objeto `listaDao` es de tipo `Iterable<PersonEntity>`. El metodo `map` itera sobre cada elemento del objeto `listadoDao` para convertirlos al tipo `PersonModel`.

La asignatura del metodo `map` en este caso es `PersonModel map(Function<PersonEntity> p)` y segun dicta el uso de las lambdas, para poder enviar un metodo como parametro, ese metodo debe de tener la misma asignatura y el metodo `personEntityToPersonModel` satisface esa condicion.

En resumen, el metodo `personEntityToPersonModel` se ejecutara por cada elemento que tenga el iterador `listaDao`. Ese codigo se puede traducir con lambdas de la siguiente manera:

```
listModels.addAll(listaDao.stream().map(personEntity->{

  // codigo del metodo personEntityToPersonModel

}).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Y funcionaria de la misma manera. Lo unico que en tu caso se envia el metodo como parametro en vez de definir una lambda.

Y por ultimo `.collect(Collectors.toList())` convierte el Stream resultante a `List<PersonModel>`.

Answer (score 0):

Explicación paso a paso:

```
listModels.addAll( //añade a la lista todos los elementos que estén en
                   // la lista que recibe como parámetro
   listaDao.stream() //convierte listaDao en un stream de objetos 
     .map( //transforma el stream de PersonEntity a un stream de PersonModel...
        this::personEntityToPersonModel //...aplicando a cada elemento este método
      ).collect(Collectors.toList()) //y guarda el stream resultante en una lista
);
```